# Cast works fine, but Convert not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I tried to Convert.ToInt16 in Contains() but it didnt work

This line of code doesnt work:

filter.OrgUnits = _context.OrgUnit.Where(x => dropdownFilterDto.ViewAllOrgUnits ? true :
staffOrgUnitsAsRegionalManager.Contains(Convert.ToInt16(x.OrgUnitParentId))

But this works just fine :

```
filter.OrgUnits = _context.OrgUnit.Where(x => dropdownFilterDto.ViewAllOrgUnits ? true : 
                  staffOrgUnitsAsRegionalManager.Contains((short)x.OrgUnitParentId)
```

Can u tell what is the difference between cast and convert?

Comment: casting is a compile-time operation. converting a runtime-thing. Anyway: what *is* `x.OrgUnitParentId`?

Comment: what does "it didn't work" even mean? What error do you get (if any)?

Comment: @BranislavRistivojević The search keyword for this is "Entityframework convert not work"

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain OrgUnitParentId is city where org units are based, js returns 500 status code with Convert.ToInt16, but  MichaelMao answered the question, thank you anyway